# Is the expression »an seinen Memoiren schreiben« correct?

Tags: sentence-structure, expression

The below paragraph comes from the article “[Obamas erster Auftritt als Ex-Präsident. "Ich bin echt alt"](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/ausland/barack-obama-in-chicago-erster-auftritt-nach-abschied-aus-weissem-haus-a-1144650.html).” in *Der Spiegel*:

> Beide [Barack and Michelle Obama] **schreiben an ihren Memoiren** und sollen dafür Berichten zufolge ein Honorar von 65 Millionen US-Dollar bekommen. Ihren Wohnsitz haben die Obamas weiterhin in Washington, wo die jüngste Tochter Sasha noch zur Schule geht.

According to [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Memoiren), the standard expression is: *seine Memoiren schreiben*.

So, is the expression *an seinen Memoiren schreiben* correct? Or is the word *anschreiben* used in the above paragraph? But shouldn't then the separable prefix *an* go after the plural noun *Memoiren*: *Beide schreiben ihren Memoiren an*? But then *ihren* should probably be *ihre*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can

> ein Buch schreiben

that denotes the whole work, from start to finish.

And if you say

> ich habe ein Buch geschrieben

we know you have finished the book.

And you can

> an einem Buch schreiben

which denotes being busy working on a book.

And if you say

> ich habe an einem Buch geschrieben

then we know you have been working on a book, but whether you have finished it or not is not said (most probably you have not, otherwise you'd been using the first phrase).

Also, compare the English *I wrote a  book* vs. *I was working on a Book*.

The same is obviously valid for any kind of book, including autobiographies.

Answer (score 6):

Nachdem du laut deinem Profil deutsche Zeitungen fließend lesen kannst, erlaube ich mir auf Deutsch zu antworten.

Ja, diese Formulierung ist korrekt, aber in

> Jemand **schreibt an** einem Buch.

sind die fett hervorgehobenen Teile nicht die Teile eines trennbaren Verbs. Das Wort *anschreiben* müsste so verwendet werden:

> Jemand **schreibt** ein Buch **an**.

Dieser Satz hätte aber eine völlig andere Bedeutung. Wichtig: Die abgetrennte Vorsilbe eines trennbaren Verbs steht immer am Ende des Satzes.

Die Formulierung

> Jemand **schreibt an** einem Buch.

entspricht

> Jemand **arbeitet an** einem Buch.

wobei eigentlich nur die Art der Arbeit genauer spezifiziert ist. Gemeint ist damit, dass das Werkstück, das durch die Arbeit verändert oder erzeugt wird, ein Buch ist.

Aber auch ohne die Präposition »an« ist der Satz korrekt, meint aber etwas geringfügig anderes:

> Jemand schreibt ein Buch.

(Beachte auch den Akkusativ anstelle des Dativs)

Diese Formulierung bedeutet, dass ein Buch erzeugt wird, ähnlich wie:

> Jemand baut ein Haus.
>   Jemand malt ein Bild.

Hier steht der Akt des Erschaffen von etwas neuem im Vordergrund. Im anderen Fall (»Jemand schreib an einem Buch«) steht die damit verbundene Arbeit im Vordergrund. Wie gesagt: Ein eher subtiler Unterschied.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that 
Beide schreiben ihre Memoiren
ist more Standard High German, though
Sie schreiben an ihren Memoiren 
is colloquial German and widely used.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question, that's why I gave -1.